# If I don't pass any value in msgstr of numerical msg id in PO file what will come out?

Tags: odoo, arabic, po

I am making an Arabic PO translation file of my odoo module 
in which there is a msgid:

```
msgid "10"
msgstr ""
```

Here I am not writing anything in msgstr, what will come out?

Will it show number "10" in string at runtime, or will it show blank as nothing is passed in msgstr?

Comment: can't you debug and see what happens?

Comment: no , I can debug , but it is 15000 lines of codes and I have just started converting so , I will debug at once after translating a whole file

Answer (score 0):

Gettext format uses empty `msgstr` strings for messages that are not yet translated. So in your example "10" will be interpreted as not translated and the original string ("10") will be used. This will **not** result in an empty string.